# Windows Phone Map control has unresponsive pinch zoom

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pinch

I'm seeing very spotty/unresponsive behavior with the silverlight map control on Windows Phone 7 (Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Map). The map control doesn't seem to pick up a lot of my pinch gestures. Is anyone else seeing this? Is there a way a workaround?

Just as an experiment I hooked up custom gesture listeners to PinchStarted, PinchDelta and PinchCompleted. My event handlers are getting fired every time I pinch, but the Silverlight map control doesn't pick them "most" of the times.

PS. I'm using the most up to date SDK/Toolkits.

Comment: Do you have anything else on the page? Have you added anythign else to the map (e.g. lots of pins, etc.)?

Comment: I have a single view with only the map control (no pushpins, layers etc).

Comment: Do you test it on a device or in the emulator?

Comment: The emulator does not have pinch zoom functionality. I tested on the Samsung SGH device.

Comment: I have a similar situation where I cannot zoom out unless the pinch first zooms in one level. Immediate zoom in fine. Immediate zoom out, nothing. Zoom in one level, and zoom out within same gesture.. works. Did you find a resolution? This only happens in my app, not in the maps app.

Comment: I believe the Maps app is not based on the Silverlight map control. It is a native "closed" source app. I wonder why MS would build a great maps app and not bundle that goodness with the platform.

Comment: After talking to our Microsoft contact we have no answers for the pinch performance problems. The official side stepped our question but and recommend putting a +/- buttons on the map for zooming in and out of the Map. To show the +/- buttons use the ZoomBarVisible property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to our Microsoft contact we have no answers for the pinch performance problems. The official side stepped our question but and recommend putting a +/- buttons on the map for zooming in and out of the Map. To show the +/- buttons use the [ZoomBarVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.core.mapbase.zoombarvisibility%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property.

Comment: This made me smile, as I was told by a microsoft Ux guy here in the uk to get rid of the +/- buttons.